# Compare which string is greater using Operator overloading in C++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I am trying string comparision using operator overloading i am using > operator , i am not getting the correct output, can you tell me what mistake i am doing here is my code

```js
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>


class strclass
{

 public:
 char s1[20];


void getdata()
 {

 cin>>s1;

 }
void showdata()
 {
 cout<<s1;
 }


  int  operator>(strclass obj)
  {
   int temp,temp1;
   temp=strlen(s1);
   temp1=strlen(obj.s1);

   if(temp>temp1)
   {
    return 1;
   }
   else
   return 0;
  }



};

void main()
{

clrscr();
  strclass obj1,obj2;
  int temp3;
  if(obj1>obj2)
  {
   cout<<"string 1 is greater";
  }
  else
  {
   cout<<"string 2 is greater";
  }


  cout<<"enter string 1"<<endl;
  obj1.getdata();
 // obj1.showdata();
  cout<<"enter string 2"<<endl;
   obj2.getdata();
//   obj2.showdata();
   getch();
}
```

I am using basic library functions. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged C++_CLI? That is Microsoft's C++ with .Net extensions and nowhere in this code do I see that you are using it. You should also be using `std::string` for strings instead of C style character arrays and C library functions.

Comment: Also, `operator>` should return `bool`, not `int`.

Comment: i wasn't aware of the tag edited it thanks

Comment: You also compare the objects before putting any data in them, which would seem to be backwards.

Comment: i have put the data in object and then i am comparing.

Comment: Not in the example above. `obj1>obj2` is before `obj1.getData()` and `obj2.GetData()`

Comment: ok i tried to add if(obj1>obj2)
  {
   cout<<"string 1 is greater";
  }
  else
  {
   cout<<"string 2 is greater";
  } after obj2.getdata();  but it says string 2 is greater than string 1 every time is put different string lengths

Comment: Why not use [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) and [`std::string::compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to put the data before comparing the strings
2. The operator should return an int
3. For your class, with a public s1 member, you should use a free function for the comparison operator, which increases encapsulation, of the form `bool operator<(strclass s1, strclass s2)` instead of a member function

Comment: i am beginner to c++ would you tell me example of operator should return int i am not understanding it

Comment: instead of comparing objects in if condition  should i use strcmp function?

Comment: Sangram Barge, you need to call getData before the comparison happens, and you need to return a boolean from the operator, not an int, true or false instead of 1 or 0.

Comment: got it let me try will get back to you!